How do I stop the array from updating itself and only displaying the last task
 <h1>Calendar and Task Creator</h1>
    <div class="navigation-text">Click the arrows to switch between months</div>
    <div class="navigation-text">Click the dates to create tasks</div>
    <?php

    $month = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('n');
    $year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y');

    // Links
    $prevMonth = ($month == 1) ? 12 : $month - 1;
    $prevYear = ($month == 1) ? $year - 1 : $year;
    $nextMonth = ($month == 12) ? 1 : $month + 1;
    $nextYear = ($month == 12) ? $year + 1 : $year;

    echo "<div class='navigation'>";
    echo "<a href='index.php?month=$prevMonth&year=$prevYear'>&lt;</a>";
    echo "<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
    echo "<a href='index.php?month=$nextMonth&year=$nextYear'>&gt;</a>";
    echo "</div>";

    // number of days 
    $numDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);

    $monthName = date('F', $firstDay);

    //day of the week for the first day of the month
    $dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);

    $daysOfWeek = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
    $firstDayIndex = array_search($dayOfWeek, $daysOfWeek);


    // Display 
    echo "<h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($daysOfWeek as $day) {
        echo "<th>$day</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $dayCount = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $firstDayIndex; $i++) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    while ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
        for ($i = $firstDayIndex; $i < 7; $i++) {
            if ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
                echo "<td><a href='form.php?day=$dayCount&month=$month&year=$year'>$dayCount</a></td>";
                $dayCount++;
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        if ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        $firstDayIndex = 0;
    }
    echo "</table>";
// ** Here is where I'm unsure what to do **
    // printing tasks
  $task_name=$_GET['task_name'];
  $day=$_GET['day'];
  $month=$_GET['month'];
  $year=$_GET['year'];
    $tasks = array(
      array(
          'name' => '$task_name', 
          'day' => $day, 
          'month' => $month, 
          'year' => $year
      ),
    );
    
    // Display 
    echo "<h2>Tasks</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Task Name</th><th>Date</th></tr>";
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$task_name}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$task['day']}/{$task['month']}/{$task['year']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>

The problem is when I enter more than one form, only the latest task is displayed. I'm not sure if I have to store it in a database or if there's another way of doing it.
I tried to make it so that if the task name is different than the first one, I added a new array to the $tasks but it still only displayed the 2nd task as the variable $task_name is still the same for both.

Yes if you want the data to be saved across multiple requests to the server then you'll need to save it somewhere - e.g. a database, or a file, and then also have code to retrieve what's stored. So you need one bit of code for saving new data, and another bit for retrieving and displaying stored data. Otherwise your PHP script can only work with what's directly submitted to it each time it runs - it doesn't remember what was submitted on previous runs.

@buff $_GET['task_name'] appears to be a single string.  If you want that value to contain multiple values, how are you planning on storing that data and how do you plan to retrieve it?  If you want it as an array, then the url can be ?task_name[]=name1&task_name[]=name2, then you can loop over $_GET['task_name'].  This is a personal/subjective decision for you to make.  I don't understand where the user is submitting these task_name values. I don't understand why the user needs to be able to load multiple tasks at once.

For this sort of scenario ideally, you should use some sort of database to store your data or persist data after each action.
If you do not like storing data in the database for the time being best is to store the data in sessions, cookies, or client-side storage facilities like local storage.
Refer to the below code to achieve what you need using the session:
<?php
session_start(); // Start or resume a session

$month = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('n');
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y');

$prevMonth = ($month == 1) ? 12 : $month - 1;
$prevYear = ($month == 1) ? $year - 1 : $year;
$nextMonth = ($month == 12) ? 1 : $month + 1;
$nextYear = ($month == 12) ? $year + 1 : $year;

echo "<div class='navigation'>";
echo "<a href='index.php?month=$prevMonth&year=$prevYear'>&lt;</a>";
echo "<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
echo "<a href='index.php?month=$nextMonth&year=$nextYear'>&gt;</a>";
echo "</div>";

    
    $numDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    
    $monthName = date('F', $firstDay);
    
    
    $dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
    
    $daysOfWeek = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
    $firstDayIndex = array_search($dayOfWeek, $daysOfWeek);
    
    
     
    echo "<h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($daysOfWeek as $day) {
        echo "<th>$day</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $dayCount = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $firstDayIndex; $i++) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    while ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
        for ($i = $firstDayIndex; $i < 7; $i++) {
            if ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
                echo "<td><a href='form.php?day=$dayCount&month=$month&year=$year'>$dayCount</a></td>";
                $dayCount++;
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        if ($dayCount <= $numDays) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        $firstDayIndex = 0;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    
    
    if (isset($_GET['task_name'], $_GET['day'], $_GET['month'], $_GET['year'])) {
        $task_name = $_GET['task_name'];
        $day = $_GET['day'];
        $month = $_GET['month'];
        $year = $_GET['year'];
    
        $_SESSION['tasks'][] = array(
            'name' => $task_name,
            'day' => $day,
            'month' => $month,
            'year' => $year
        );
    }
    
    
    echo "<h2>Tasks</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Task Name</th><th>Date</th></tr>";
    if (isset($_SESSION['tasks'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['tasks'] as $task) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$task['name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$task['day']}/{$task['month']}/{$task['year']}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    
?>


It still only shows the last task. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my other files or something?
